# error on loading a pb model in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

this is the error info

```
_RemoveDefaultAttrs(op_dict, producer_op_list, graph_def)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 227, in _RemoveDefaultAttrs
op_def = op_dict[node.op]
KeyError: 'DivNoNan'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41vKV.png)

Comment: Hey @ericsu, could you please provide us with code you have tried to help users?

Comment: Have you checked whether you're restoring the model with the same version of Tensorflow that was used to save it?